# Convert a list of variable length Tuples into Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of variable length tuples. How do I convert it to a dictionary?

```
tup = [ ("x", 1), ("x", 2, 4), ("x", 3), ("y", 1), ("y", 2), ("z", 1), ("z", 2, 3) ]
```

I am getting below error when using Comprehension

```
{key: [i[1:] for i in tup if i[0] == key] for (key, value) in tup}
```

Error:

```
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last)
>ipython-input-26-bedcc2e8a704< in module()
----> 1 {key: [i[1] for i in tuplex if i[0] == key] for (key, value) in tuplex}  
>ipython-input-26-bedcc2e8a704< in dictcomp((key, value))
----> 1 {key: [i[1] for i in tuplex if i[0] == key] for (key, value) in tuplex}  
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Expected output:

```
{'x': [1, 2, 4, 3], 'y': [1, 2], 'z': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @schwobaseggl  {'x': [1, 2, 4,3], 'y': [1, 2], 'z': [1, 2,3]}

Comment: Hi @codename47, please make sure to always post important information like expected output into the question itself. Comments aren't exactly temporary, so there not the best place to put information. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a task for a list comprehension. You can do this with a simple `for` loop using the dictionary's [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to set the default value of a key to an empty list and then [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) that list with the values in that tuple:

```
tup = [ ("x", 1), ("x", 2, 4), ("x", 3), ("y", 1), ("y", 2), ("z", 1), ("z", 2, 3) ]

res = {}
for k, *rest in tup:
    res.setdefault(k, []).extend(rest)

print(res)
# {'y': [1, 2], 'x': [1, 2, 4, 3], 'z': [1, 2, 3]}
```

For Python 2.7, I don't think you can unpack a tuple like that, so you can try something like:

```
for t in tup:
    res.setdefault(t[0], []).extend(t[1:])
```

Comment: Can you suggest a solution for python2.7 ? This works fine for python3.4. Thanks

Comment: @codename47 see updated answer. You'll have to manually access the key in the tuple with the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
tup = [("x", 1), ("x", 2, 4), ("x", 3), ("y", 1), ("y", 2), ("z", 1), ("z", 2, 3)]
data = {}
for item in tup:
    if item[0] in data:
        data[item[0]] = data[item[0]] + list(item[1:])
    else:
        data[item[0]] = list(item[1:])
print(data)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.